# SQL Select - How to Select Values from other tables based on one's foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

[image]

I want to have a select statement that has the sport, league and season columns from the server_slseason, but uses the server_sport.name, server_season.year and server_league.name as values

I tried a couple of statements, but none of them worked.

Also in server_slseason, all the columns are foreign keys referencing their primary keys.

Comment: Google `Inner join` in mysql

Comment: Use text to describe your tables, not images. I find it very hard to read the text in those boxes.

Comment: Toni, it would be good for you if you could post the couple of statements you tried, so we may guide you. This query is of a very low difficulty, so you'll have to get into that query construction logic rather fast.

Comment: What have you tried???  The best way to learn something is to try it yourself.  If you don't know how to write a SQL query, read some introductory SQL books.

Answer (score 0):

found a query`

```
select server_sport.name, server_season.year, server_league.name from server_slseason 
inner join server_sport on server_slseason.sport = server_sport.id 
inner join server_season on server_slseason.season = server_season.id
inner join server_league on server_slseason.league = server_league.id;
```

`